# Button inside View with Flex dimensions has his text truncated

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, react-native, react-native-flexbox

I'm new to react-native and mobile app development in general and I'm trying to create a header for my App with a Text and a Button inside it.

Here is my code :

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

    export default class App extends React.Component {

      _leaveSheet() {

      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
              <Text allowFontScaling={false} style={styles.titleText}>YATHZEE</Text>
              <Button style={styles.leaveButton} title="Quitter" onPress={this._leaveSheet}/>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.body}></View>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column'
      },
      header: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#BDBDBD',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
      },
      body: {
        flex: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
      },
      titleText: {
        // fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        // alignSelf: 'center',
        flex: 1
      },
      leaveButton: {
        // alignSelf: 'center',
        // width: '100'
        flex: 2
      }
    });
```

So I put my header with the flexDirection to row and I added inside my View my Text and my Button elements with flex: 1 and flex: 2 so I was expecting this result :

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ognN.png)

But instead I have this : the text inside the Button is truncated and my button does not take the space he should take.

[Rendering on the mobile App (OP3 phone)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayw8U.jpg)

I tried to play with the alignSelf property and width but nothing seems to work.

In facebook Button exemples I can see that Button can define the width of the Button but I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap `Button` inside a flex-ed `View` to make it happen.

```js
<View style={styles.leaveButton}>
   <Button title="Quitter" onPress={this._leaveSheet} />
</View>
```

From [react-native material design](https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design.github.io/blob/master/components/button.md),

> The button component renders a touchable button with consumes the **full
>   width of it's parent container**.